# Joblib on a slurm cluster : LokyProcess failed

Tags: python, slurm, joblib

I am using joblib for python parallelization of a code. On my laptop, it works very well. On a medium-size cluster using slurm, I systematically get an error saying "LokyProcess-xxx failed with traceback":

```
LokyProcess-139 failed with traceback: 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):

[...]

joblib.externals.loky.process_executor.TerminatedWorkerError: A worker process managed by the executor was unexpectedly terminated. This could be caused by a segmentation fault while calling the function or by an excessive memory usage causing the Operating System to kill the worker.
```

Any explanation on the origin of the error? Any suggestion to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error traceback indicates that a worker process was unexpectedly terminated due to a segmentation fault or because of excessive memory usage causing the Operating System to kill the worker. This type of error often arises when using parallel computation in environments where resources are shared among multiple users, such as a cluster.

The error messages related to "No such file or directory" are caused by the fact that when a new process is spawned in joblib, it creates a new semaphore (a low-level synchronization primitive) and associated with it a file. This file appears to be missing in your case, which may be due to two reasons:

1. File System: Your cluster may be using a network file system that doesn't fully support the semantics that Python's multiprocessing (and by extension joblib) relies on for synchronization primitives. This could be especially true if your /tmp directory, which is often used for such files, is mapped to a network file system.
2. Cleanup: Something else (another process, or perhaps a periodic cleanup script) might be deleting the semaphore files before the joblib processes have finished using them.

A common solution to this issue is to set the JOBLIB_TEMP_FOLDER environment variable to a directory on a file system that does support the necessary operations, typically a local file system.

In your bash script that you use to submit the job, you can add the following line before executing the Python script:

```
export JOBLIB_TEMP_FOLDER=/tmp/$USER
mkdir -p /tmp/$USER
```

Please replace /tmp/$USER with an appropriate directory if necessary.

Then try rerunning your job. If the error persists, it might be due to memory management issues, in which case you might need to request more memory for your job or limit the memory usage of your processes.